# AFNetworking 2.0. How check reachability status for socket (managerForAddress:)?

Tags: afnetworking, reachability

I install AFNetworking 2.0 with "pod install", and use App.xcworkspace.
With AFNetworking 2.0 I successfully send POST request, but with reachability I have problem.
I need to monitor when socket is opened and closed, my code not work, what I forgot?

```
// Check server socket available
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_len = sizeof(serverAddr);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.108");

AFNetworkReachabilityManager *reachability = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForAddress:&serverAddr];
[reachability setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"No Internet Connection");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"WIFI");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"3G");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown network status");
            break;
    }
}];
[reachability startMonitoring];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue. Looks like AFNetworking's callback mechanism doesn't work as it should - check out AFNetworkReachabilityManager's `startMonitoring` method: there's an:

```
        if (strongSelf.networkReachabilityStatusBlock) {...
```

which seems to fail no matter if you've set up a callback or not.

To fix this, I've added the following method to AFNetworkReachabilityManager:

```
- (void)startMonitoringWithStatusChangeBlock:(void (^)(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status))block
{
    [self stopMonitoring];

    if (!self.networkReachability) {
        return;
    }

    __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    AFNetworkReachabilityStatusBlock callback = ^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;

        strongSelf.networkReachabilityStatus = status;
        if (block) {
            block(status);
        }
    };

    SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {0, (__bridge void *)callback, AFNetworkReachabilityRetainCallback, AFNetworkReachabilityReleaseCallback, NULL};
    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(self.networkReachability, AFNetworkReachabilityCallback, &context);

    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(self.networkReachability, &flags);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status = AFNetworkReachabilityStatusForFlags(flags);
        callback(status);
    });

    SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop(self.networkReachability, CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}
```

This basically does the same thing but references the block from the method parameter rather than from the reachability manager's property.